# d3 tooltip removes my axis (and doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, tooltip, d3.js, mouseover, jsfiddle

I am trying to add tooltips to my D3 graph here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ericps/b5v4R/1/

but adding these mouseevents mess up how everything is rendered and I don't know why. It is a line graph with axis

```
dots.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", open_line.x())
    .attr("cy", open_line.y())
    .attr("r",3.5)
    .on("mouseover", myMouseOverFunction)
    .on("mouseout", myMouseOutFunction);
```

commenting out both `.on` methods at line 144 makes everything render how I expect it to

any insight into this?

The tooltips are based on this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ericps/E4vrX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `myMouseOverFunction`.

Simply defining the function will render your graph correctly (with the axes), allowing you to properly define your MouseOver functionality.

```
var myMouseOverFunction = function() {}
```

You can see an updated response to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sahhhm/hQgbc/
This could be implemented differently, but just a quick change was to remove the .FILL definition in your CSS and instead populating that value when creating the dot itself.

Comment: yes you were right! don't know how I didn't see that. The next mystery is that it does not work

Comment: Take a look at my edit above.. it contains a link to a new JSfiddle that should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Few problems:

mouse:

The d3.mouse(container) function gives mouse location relative to the container (a node). You specified `d3.mouse(this)`, but this is referring to the circle node, while you want to refer to the svg container: `d3.select("svg").node()`.

infobox:

The infobox div was not defined anywhere, so nothing to be shown.

See updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5v4R/4/

Comment: good pointing that out, in my production server I still can't get the tooltips to show up. does `var circle = d3.select(this);` in onmouseover need to select something else too instead of `this`